# Input file on razor page C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to edit the User information with edit razor page view. When I click in Edit button, its retrieves all user data from database including the user picture but the input (type="file") don't get it and then, when I save the edition, I am losing the user picture because its null on the input.

How can solve it? Can I load the `@Model.Picture` in the input on edit action?

Thanks all!

Comment: Do you want to view the picture and also provide user with option to replace it ? Also please provide details on how the picture is saved in database. is it saved in database directly or is a location to a file on the server ?

Comment: Hi! I am using HttpPostedFileBase in controller code (MVC app). I just want that the edit action mantein the same picture if user don't change it.

Comment: there are 2 things you should consider. 1) if you want the user to be able to select a new picture, then provide them with the input=file option that you already have on page. This will post the newly selected image that you can save. Just check the value != null before overwriting your record, 2) to view the existing picture saved in your db, render/show the picture using different variable. do not use the same variable as for saving. Provide more details in the question about the user data object and how the image is saved and how you are loading it. to get better answer.